# Access an element of a 2d dynamic array--c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I created a dynamic array.

```
typedef float* DynamicMatrix[MAT_SIZE];
DynamicMatrix matDyn;
// allocate rows and initialize to 0
    for (r = 0; r < MAT_SIZE; r++) {
        matDyn[r] = new float[MAT_SIZE];
        for (c = 0; c < MAT_SIZE; c++) {
            (matDyn[r])[c] = 0; // IS THIS CORRECT???
        }
    }
```

The whole idea was that I create an array of pointers which is my spine of a matrix I am creating. This spine is the leftmost-vertical part of the matrix. Each row of this array will point to another array of floats, therefore making it a dynamic 2d array.
I am unsure how to access an element of this matrix. Please let me know how to.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` or `boost::multi_array`?

Comment: I am creating this for an assignment which requires I use a dynamic array this way

Comment: `matDyn[r][c] = 0;`is also good

Comment: Does `DynamicMatrix` have an overload for `operator[]`?

Comment: [Dynamic Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) != [Dynamically *Allocated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation)

Answer (score 1):

You can access it just like a "normal" matrix:

`matDyn[r][c]`.

Comment: when i set elements using this same method, I get a segmentation fault 11.

Answer (score -1):

You can just access it by stating matDyn[r][c]

My error was that later in my program(not shown), I was trying to set matDyn[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE] which isn't possible (it can only be matDyn[MAT_SIZE-1][MAT_SIZE-1]) and that is why I was getting my segmentation error.